# Python-ic way of separating settings.py PROD and DEBUG constants?

Tags: python, config

I've got an app that has multiple components written in python (Redis cache, MariaDB, flask API etc.). I'm creating a settings.py file to get all my constants in one place (REDIS_URL, REDIS_IP, REDIS_PORT... *etc.*). The way I have things set up currently is...

```
run/run_app_debug.py
  settings.init_debug()
  # now settings will return the "debug" constants

run/run_app_prod.py
  # no change to settings

lib/update_cache.py
  # how settings get used...
  redis_server = redis.Redis(host=settings.REDIS_IP, port=settings.REDIS_PORT)

settings.py
  REDIS_IP = '1.2.3.4'
  REDIS_PORT = 6379
  REDIS_URL = 'redis://{}:{}'.format(REDIS_IP, REDIS_PORT)
  # ...
  def init_debug():
    REDIS_IP = '127.0.0.1'
    # ...
```

Is there a more python-ic way of doing this, or any suggestions on how best to restructure this "settings.py" file, or some other more elegant way of having a central python config that can broadcast important constants to the rest of the app?

Comment: Have you considered making a base class (e.g. `BaseConfig`) containing all of your constants as "static" members, and then overriding them as needed in specific environmental subclasses (e.g. `DevConfig` and `ProdConfig`)? Then you could make a factory to instantiate the configuration you want based on the environment.

Comment: Awesome, I'm liking this! So I'll have something like `config = settings.get_config()` at the top of my files, which will return the appropriate class reference, based on whether `DEBUG` has been set or not, then I can go ahead and use `config.REDIS_URL`... assuming no one surfaces anything clearer in the near future, I'll go ahead and use this; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, I typically create a base configuration class, and then extend that base class to create the configurations that I need for each environment. Then, I create a factory class with a static method that instantiates the appropriate configuration class for me.

An example of this is below. Note that I add `IS_DEV` and `IS_PROD` into the corresponding configuration classes so that I can tell where my app is running whenever I have access the configuration instance.

```
### inside some config.py file
### ...

__all__ = ['ConfigFactory']

class ConfigFactory(object):
    """
    Factory class for generating the proper configuration
    based on the environment in which we are running
    """

    @staticmethod
    def get_config():
        if os.getenv('PRODUCTION_VARIABLE') is not None:
            return _ProductionConfig()
        return _DevelopmentConfig()


class _BaseConfig(object):

    DEBUG = False
    IMPORTANT_VAR = False
    SPECIAL_VAR = os.getenv('SPECIAL_VAR', 'NOTSET')

class _DevelopmentConfig(_BaseConfig):

    DEBUG = True
    IS_DEV = True

class _ProductionConfig(_BaseConfig):

    IMPORTANT_VAR = True
    IS_PROD = True
```